# During TestCase execution django.db.connection.cursor() SQL query returning data from main DB, not from the test one

Tags: python, django, pytest

I'm facing a problem which I have no more ideas how to resolve.

I have need to test data which is returned by direct query from database.
During execution of TestCase `django.db.connection.cursor()` is returning data from main database, not from test one, which contain fixtures prepared for this test purposes.

I've tried to use both **TestCase** and **TransactionalTestCase**. 
I've tried debugging, checking variables values and found out that **connection** is pointed onto test database for sure.

Do you know why it's returning data from main database? Is there any case when Django is copying data from main database to this created for tests purposes?

I'm using: `Python 3.6.5`, `Django 2.1`, `pytest 4.6.3`, `pytest-django 3.5`

Thanks in advance for any support.

---

**Follow-up**

Dears,

That problem occurs only while trying to [perform custom **raw SQL Query** directly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) inside **Test Case.** [Retrieving objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects) by standard Django QuerySets works fine.

Do you have any idea why this specific way to retrieve data from db not working during test execution?

Comment: can you post you settings.py file?

Comment: Please find below part of settings.py responsible for DB connections. Is that enough?

`DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'xxx',
        'USER': 'xxx_django',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxx',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '7177',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
        },
    },
} `

Answer (score 0):

I found [an answer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database) in Django documentation:

> If your code attempts to access the database when its modules are compiled, this will occur before the test database is set up, with potentially unexpected results.

Still - if you know any way to avoid affecting tests by production data while raw sql queries are performed I would love to know how to do it.